# Is there a set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ whose set of accumulation points is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$? Not using closed/open properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there a set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ whose set of accumulation points is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$? Either give an example of such a $B$ or explain why $B$ cannot exist.

Here is what I am thinking:

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there will be infinitely many rational numbers in the neighbourhood of any irrational number and so $\mathbb{Q}$ will have accumulation points not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Because of this, for a more formal reason I am having trouble coming up with, we can construct no such set.

Note: we have not learned anything about open and closed sets.

Comment: The set of accumulation points of a set is always closed.

Comment: How do we construct that set? And the set of accumulation points of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You don’t really have to construct it: just show that if $A$ is any set, and $A'$ is the set of its accumulation points, then $A'$ is closed. The easiest way to do this is to show that the complement of $A'$ is open. Don’t think about $\Bbb Q$ at all at this point.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is an open set there is no such set?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is *not* an open set. However, it’s also not closed, which means that it cannot be the set of accumulation points of any set.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have thought about the openness of the rationals a little harder. It is not closed nor it is open.

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is a set, and we let $B'$ indicate its set of accumulation points, then we can fairly readily show that the complement of $B'$ is open, and so $B'$ is closed.

Since $\Bbb Q$ is not closed in $\Bbb R,$ then it cannot be a set of accumulation points of a set of real numbers.

---

**Added**: For an alternative approach that doesn't use the concepts of open/closed sets, we can instead proceed as follows:

- Let $B'$ be the set of all accumulation points of $B,$ as before.
- Show that if $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $x_0\notin B',$ then $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\notin B'\}$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$.
- Demonstrate that there is an $x_0\in\{x\in\Bbb R:x\notin\Bbb Q\}$ for which $\Bbb I$ is not a neighborhood of $x_0.$
- Conclude.

Comment: So all we care about is whether or not the rationals are closed because if we have a set of accumulation points it must be closed?

Comment: That's it! Contrapositive proofs are wonderful things, sometimes.

Comment: If every accumulation point of a set does not belong to it then it will not be closed?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get it. We have the set of the rationals which is not closed. So we assert that it cannot be the set of ALL accumulation points of any set because of this?

Comment: That depends on what you mean. If for some set $B,$ there is some $x\in B'$ such that $x\notin B$ (that is, there is an accumulation point of $B$ that doesn't belong to $B$), then indeed $B$ is not closed, since a set is closed if and only if every accumulation point of the set belongs to it. If, on the other hand, you mean that $B\cap B'=\emptyset$ (that is, that *none* of the accumulation points of $B$ belong to $B$), then it may still be closed--specifically, it will be (vacuously) closed if and only if $B'=\emptyset.$

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that if we take a set of accumulations points $B'$ from a set $B$. If that set $B'$ is not closed then it is not all of the accumulation points of $B$.

Comment: Since there are accumulation points of $\Bbb Q$ that don't belong to $\Bbb Q,$ then $\Bbb Q$ is not closed, yes. Now, if $A$ is a subset of $B'$ (which is usually used to denote the set of *all* accumulation points of $B$ in this context) and $A$ is not closed, then $A\ne B'$ since $B'$ is closed. Thus, while $\Bbb Q$ may be *a* set of accumulation points of some set $B$ of real numbers, it cannot be the set of *all* accumulation points of such a set $B$ (indeed, if $\Bbb Q\subseteq B',$ then $B'=\Bbb R$).

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. Now, can we do this without knowing anything about closed or open sets? That's when this question was posed in my analysis class.

Comment: We can, but I'll need to know your definition of "accumulation point" to tell you *how* to do it.

Comment: Definition: Let $S$ be a set of real numbers. A real number $A$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if and only if every neighborhood of $A$ contains infinitely many points of $S$.

Comment: Okay, define "neighborhood," then.

Comment: A set $Q$ of real numbers is a neigborhood of a real number of a real number $x$ if and only if $Q$ contains an interval of positive length centered at $x$-that is, if and only if there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq Q$

Comment: Got it! I have updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if you have any more questions about it.